# Plot data with alpha values resulting in one color image - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, opacity, imshow

I'm trying to plot a certain data with opacity values.

To plot it without opacity, I can do this:

```
plt.figure()
fig = plt.imshow(scalar_field, origin='lower', zorder=1, extent=(-4, 4, -4, 4))
plt.colorbar(fig)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Which gives me that image:

[image]

But I have some opacity values that should be included. Then, I do the following:

```
plt.figure()
data = plt.cm.jet(scalar_field)
data[..., 3] = 1.0 # just for tests purposes
fig = plt.imshow(data, origin='lower', extent=(-4, 4, -4, 4))
plt.colorbar(fig)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

Which is correct, since `vmin=0.0` and `vmax=1.0` and my values are too small.

So, to properly see something, I do this:

```
plt.figure()
data = plt.cm.jet(scalar_field)
data[..., 3] = 1.0 # just for tests purposes
max_lim = numpy.max(field_property)
min_lim = numpy.min(field_property)
fig = plt.imshow(data, origin='lower', extent=(-4, 4, -4, 4), vmin=min_lim, vmax=max_lim, cmap=plt.cm.jet))
plt.colorbar(fig)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Which properly adjust the image limits as the ones showed in the first figure:

However, I can't see the image yet. In both cases, I can see something like a weird blue circle in the images.

[image]

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using alpha= in imshow instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is the fact that calling a `cmap` with some value assumes fixed values. If you pass a `float`, the range of the cmap is fixed between 0 and 1. If you pass an `int` the range is 0 to 255. You are, apparently, passing very small values to the `cmap` which then returns colors equal or close to the value 0 (so Blue for jet).

You then pass this 'color array' to imshow, this assumes and displays the array as an RGB(A) image. Any `vmin`, `vmax` and `cmap` stuff you add is ignored, because its already a RGB image, there is nothing to map.

What you want to do is create a `ScalarMappable` which you can create with a `cmap` AND a `normalizer` which sets the range.

Since you dont define your 'scalar_field' i'll use some sample data from the MPL Gallery:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

# create the sample data
# after http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_levels.html
dx, dy = 0.05, 0.05
y, x = np.mgrid[slice(1, 5 + dy, dy),
                slice(1, 5 + dx, dx)]

z = np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x) * np.cos(x)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ax.axis('off')

# with a normalizer you can set the range against which you want to map
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-1, vmax=1)
# the cmap of your choice
cmap = plt.cm.jet

# create a 'mapper'
mapper = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)

# map the data to a rgba array
rgba = mapper.to_rgba(z)

# make some adjustments to the alpha
rgba[:,:,3] = 0.5

# and plot
# there is no need for vmin, cmap etc keywords, its already rgba
ax.imshow(rgba)
```

Comment: +1 You could actually remove a step or two by doing `rgba = cmap(norm(z))`.  There's no need to explicitly make a `ScalarMappable` instance. (`ScalarMappable` is typically used similarly to an abstract base class. Lots of artists inherit from it, but you rarely use it directly.)

Comment: Just one thing, @RutgerKassies. I had to use the `vmin`, `vmax` parameters in order to display the colobar varying according to my true range, and not 0.0 to 1.0 (even doing, of course, `norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=my_min_lim, vmax=my_max_lim))`. Thank you. (:

Comment: Alternatively you could probably also add 'norm=norm', as a keyword to imshow. Glad it helped you.